# Vhs object is null in videojs

Tags: javascript, video.js

I am new to java script. I am trying to do a project on videojs.
I am not able to get the vhs object in the below code. What wrong I am doing?

```
</head>
<body>
  <h1>This is a demo video</h1>

  <video-js id="demo_video" class="vjs-default-skin" controls preload="auto" width="640" height="268">
    <source src="http://127.0.0.1:8887/video/filename.m3u8" type="application/x-mpegURL">
  </video-js>


  
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/video.js/dist/video.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/@videojs/http-streaming/dist/videojs-http-streaming.js"></script>
  <script>
    var player = videojs("demo_video");
    var vhs = player.tech().vhs;
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The below code return as `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'vhs' of undefined`

```
var vhs = player.tech().vhs;
```

Answer (score 2):

I have 2 suggestions, second one is I think the issue is.

1. Make sure you have the proper version of the libraries.
2. vhs is the runtime property which is attached to the tech object, you can only use it when HLS is in use. So make sure the HLS streaming protocol is in use when you call that.

Comment: I have noticed that when I open the console in chrome I can get the vhs object using `player.tech().vhs` but not when I am trying to access the object using script tag in html I am not getting the vhs object. When I am trying to access the object using setTimeout with 3 sec, I can access the vhs object in script tag in html. This lead me to assume the vhs object is not available when the script loads.

Comment: @user2588083 yes, that is my #2 point, it will only be available when the video is loaded and HLS streaming protocol is working. Please dont forget to mark this answer if this helps you :)

Comment: How to know if HLS is in use and then call vhs

Answer (score 0):

I found in this discussion that types for VHS are not provided and that we should use:

`(player.tech() as any).vhs`

https://github.com/videojs/http-streaming/issues/796